# WinRT: How to determine current Mouse/Pointer position

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, winrt-xaml

In WinRT there impossible to reorder items of `GridView` if `ItemsSource` is grouped. I've decided to workaround this by using Drag&Drop functionality of `GridView`. On `Drop` event handler of `GridView` I need to find current mouse (or pointer) position to determine exact object on which my dragged item is dropped (or nearest one).

So is there any way to get this position?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [DragEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.drageventargs.aspx) to get the position.